# How to get variable value as table name in select statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
SET Project_List_val=CONCAT(Project_Number_val,'_List');
Insert Into test (Manthan_Panel_Id) select Manthan_Panel_Id from Project_List_val where Project_Number_val='9';
```

In the insert statement there is the variable named 'Project_List_val' which consist of table name as concated in the above step. This statement is not taking the content of the variable as table name instead it is taking 'Project_List_val' as table name and giving table not found error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default *you cannot parameterized* table names and column names so you need to create *Dynamic SQL* for that,

```
SET @Project_List_val = CONCAT(Project_Number_val, '_List');
SET @projNum = 9;
SET @sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO test (Manthan_Panel_Id)
                    SELECT Manthan_Panel_Id 
                    FROM ', @Project_List_val, ' 
                    WHERE Project_Number_val = ?');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @projNum;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1